# "You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type" with Webpack and Babel

Tags: javascript, webpack, babeljs, es6-module-loader

I am trying to use Webpack with Babel to compile ES6 assets, but I am getting the following error message:

```
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| import React from 'react';
| /*
| import { render } from 'react-dom'
```

Here is what my Webpack config looks like:

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  entry: './index',
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    publicPath: '/dist/'
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Here is the middleware step that makes use of Webpack:

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var webpackDevMiddleware = require('webpack-dev-middleware');
var config = require('./webpack.config');

var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var port = 3000;

var compiler = webpack(config);
app.use(webpackDevMiddleware(compiler, {
  noInfo: true,
  publicPath: config.output.publicPath
}));

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

app.listen(port, function(err) {
  console.log('Server started on http://localhost:%s', port);
});
```

All my index.js file is doing is importing react, but it seems like the 'babel-loader' is not working.

I am using 'babel-loader' 6.0.0.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. babel-preset-es2015 is installed and yet it still has issues with using JSX in a ReactDOM.render() call :s

Comment: What is the extensions of your file? Are they js files or jsx files? Your loader only considers files with jsx extensions, that could be the problem

Comment: At this link your problem will be 100% solved [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50149729/next-js-import-css-file-does-not-work/57543284#57543284][1]

Comment: At this link your problem will be 100% solved [css import to next.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50149729/next-js-import-css-file-does-not-work/57543284#57543284)

Answer (score 110, accepted):

**NOTE:** The following applies for Babel 6.x and Webpack 1.x. See the end for an update.

You need to install the `es2015` preset:

```
npm install babel-preset-es2015
```

and then configure `babel-loader`:

```
{
    test: /\.jsx?$/,
    loader: 'babel-loader',
    exclude: /node_modules/,
    query: {
        presets: ['es2015']
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:** For those coming across this question with more recent versions of Babel or Webpack:

- For Babel >= 7.x, you should be using `@babel/preset-env`
- For Webpack >= 2.x, you should be using `options` instead of `query`

Comment: I have presets installed and babel-loader installed too. It is still giving the same error

Comment: @UG_ You'll have to ask a separate question. We'd need to see your whole config and the full error message.

Comment: @UG_ did you find the solution?

Comment: Where is the file "babel-loader" file that we should configure?

Comment: @nix86 `babel-loader` is an npm module, not a file you edit.

Comment: What's `query`? `unknown property 'query'`

Comment: @404usernamenotfound Edited the answer

Answer (score 43):

Make sure you have the **es2015 babel preset** installed.

An example **package.json** devDependencies is:

```
"devDependencies": {
  "babel-core": "^6.0.20",
  "babel-loader": "^6.0.1",
  "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.0.15",
  "babel-preset-react": "^6.0.15",
  "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.0.15",
  "webpack": "^1.9.6",
  "webpack-dev-middleware": "^1.2.0",
  "webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.0.0"
},
```

Now configure **babel-loader** in your webpack config:

```
{ test: /\.js$/, loader: 'babel-loader', exclude: /node_modules/ }
```

add a **.babelrc** file to the root of your project where the node modules are:

```
{
  "presets": ["es2015", "stage-0", "react"]
}
```

More info:

- [babeljs.io - using babel with webpack](http://babeljs.io/docs/setup/#webpack)
- [babeljs.io - docs on .babelrc](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/babelrc/)
- [react-webpack-cookbook - configure react with webpack](https://christianalfoni.github.io/react-webpack-cookbook/Configuring-react-js.html)
- [a react-webpack-example repo](https://github.com/StevenIseki/react-webpack-example)

Comment: . babelrc file is what I was missing, thanks! This is the complete tutorial, the accepted answer only gets you so far.

Comment: Side-info: Not so sure about "stage-0" in options (can also be configured in .babelrc): Some features may not make it in official ES-Standards, so I usually use the more safe "stage-3".

Answer (score 18):

If you are using Webpack > 3 then you only need to install `babel-preset-env`, since this preset accounts for es2015, es2016 and es2017.

```
var path = require('path');
let webpack = require("webpack");

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        app: './app/App.js',
        vendor: ["react","react-dom"]
    },
    output: {
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, '../public')
    },
    module: {
        rules: [{
            test: /\.jsx?$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            use: {
                loader: 'babel-loader?cacheDirectory=true',
            }
        }]
    }
};
```

This picks up its configuration from my `.babelrc` file:

```
{
    "presets": [
        [
            "env",
            {
                "targets": {
                    "browsers":["last 2 versions"],
                    "node":"current"
                }
            }
        ],["react"]
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 14):

**BABEL TEAM UPDATE:**

We're super  excited that you're trying to use ES2015 syntax, but instead of continuing yearly presets, the team recommends using babel-preset-env. By default, it has the same behavior as previous presets to compile ES2015+ to ES5

If you are using **Babel version 7** you will need to run npm install **@babel/preset-env** and have "presets": ["@babel/preset-env"] in your `.babelrc` configuration.

This will compile all latest features to **es5** transpiled code:

**Prerequisites**:

1. Webpack 4+
2. Babel 7+

**Step-1:**: npm install --save-dev @babel/preset-env

**Step-2:** In order to compile `JSX` code to es5 babel provides `@babel/preset-react` package to convert react`jsx` extension file to native browser understandable code.

**Step-3:** npm install --save-dev @babel/preset-react

**Step-4:** create `.babelrc` file inside root path path of your project where `webpack.config.js` exists.

```
{
  "presets": ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"]
}
```

**Step-5:** webpack.config.js

```
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    mode: 'development',
    entry: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/index.js'),
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'output'),
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js', '.jsx']
    },
    module: {
        rules: [{
                test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'babel-loader'
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/i,
                use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: "./public/index.html",
            filename: "./index.html"
         })
    ]
}
```

Comment: I'm also super excited that you give devs more headaches with all your changes.

Answer (score 11):

In my case, I had such error since import path was wrong:

Wrong:
`import Select from "react-select/src/Select"; // it was auto-generated by IDE ;)`

Correct:
`import Select from "react-select";`

Answer (score 5):

This makes me feel stupid, but I want to share for anyone that got frustrated like me: I used `webpack.dev.js` but didn't specify that as the config file! When running Webpack run with:

```
webpack --config webpack.dev.js
```

And it suddenly worked ;)

Comment: Surprise , its fixed the issue for me also .
"build": "webpack --config webpack.dev.js" , 
 Thank you

Answer (score 3):

Due to updates and changes overtime, version compatibility start causing issues with configuration.

Your webpack.config.js should be like this you can also configure how ever you dim fit.

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require("webpack");

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/js/app.js',
  devtool: 'source-map',
    mode: 'development',
  module: {
    rules: [{
      test: /\.js$/,
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      use: ["babel-loader"]
    },{
      test: /\.css$/,
      use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader']
    }]
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, './src/vendor'),
    filename: 'bundle.min.js'
  }
};
```

Another Thing to notice it's the change of args, you should read babel documentation https://babeljs.io/docs/en/presets

```
.babelrc

{
    "presets": ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"]
}
```

NB: you have to make sure you have the above @babel/preset-env & @babel/preset-react installed in your package.json dependencies

Comment: Adding `@babel/preset-react` fixed it for me.

Answer (score 3):

You probably forgot to add `.js` extension to your file.

`Component` -> `Component.js`

Comment: I can't believe this was my issue, I didn't see it after creating the document.

Answer (score 2):

**Outdated babel packages on Jan 3, 2023**

Please install these list of packages for configuration with babel.

```
$ npm add -D @babel/core babel-loader @babel/preset-env @babel/preset-react
```

and add below code `.babelrc` file

```
{
    "presets": [
        "@babel/preset-env",
        "@babel/preset-react"
    ]
}
```

I used **@khizer** webpack configuration in my application

**Credit goes to [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62089763/5305430) answer**. As I have have been gone through the many answer of this solution and it tooks my 2-3 hours. I hope others don't waste the same amount of time.

Answer (score 1):

Just adding on another reason such error showed up **in Angular**.. was because I checked for html file in list of styles:

```
@Component({
selector: ...,
templateUrls: 'xyz.html',
stylesUrls: ['xyz.html']                  // problem 
})
```

Addressing wrong file type raises this error

Answer (score 1):

As question doesn't specify if it was for angular, react, or react-native. I am posting this for `react-native` and it may be implied on others too. The reason was that it wasn't able to understand the syntax specified by loader. e.g. `tsx`, `jsx`. One solution I found in this [article](https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/6157#issuecomment-581147404) after lots of exploration. When we use external library that was using `jsx` and you configured your project with `tsx`, it won't understand `jsx` and will give you to add appropriate loader. So, you can fix that by following code in your `app.json` file.

```
"web": {
  "build": {
    "babel": {
      "include": [
        "name-of-my-shared-package-here"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

By replacing `name-of-my-shared-package-here` with your package name that is causing the issue will solve this issue. You can check the package name in error that is causing this issue.

Answer (score 0):

**When using Typescript:**

In my case I used the newer syntax of webpack v3.11 from their documentation page
I just copied the css and style loaders configuration form their website.
The commented out code (newer API) causes this error, see below.

```
  module: {
        loaders: [{
                test: /\.ts$/,
                loaders: ['ts-loader']
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                loaders: [
                    'style-loader',
                    'css-loader'
                ]
            }
        ]
        // ,
        // rules: [{
        //     test: /\.css$/,
        //     use: [
        //         'style-loader',
        //         'css-loader'
        //     ]
        // }]
    }
```

The right way is to put this:

```
    {
        test: /\.css$/,
        loaders: [
            'style-loader',
            'css-loader'
        ]
    }
```

in the array of the loaders property.

Answer (score 0):

This one throw me for a spin.
Angular 7, Webpack
I found this article so I want to give credit to the Article
https://www.edc4it.com/blog/web/helloworld-angular2.html

What the solution is:
//on your component file.  use template as webpack will treat it as text
 template: require('./process.component.html')

for karma to interpret it
npm install add html-loader --save-dev
            {
                test: /.html$/,
                use: "html-loader"
            },

Hope this helps somebody

Answer (score 0):

Just add this code webpackmix.js

```
mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
    .postCss('resources/css/app.css', 'public/css',  [
        require('tailwindcss'),
    ]).vue();
```