# Error with module parsing- Webpack

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I am trying to learn to use webpack with react, while compiling I am getting this error.

ERROR in ./App.js

```
Module parse failed: D:\Reactjs\App.js Line 1: Unexpected token
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| import React from 'react';
|
| class App extends React.Component {
```

My webpack.config

```
module.exports ={
entry:"./App.js",

output: {
    path:__dirname,
    filename:'app.js'
},

module:{
    loader:[{
        test: /\.es6\.js$/, loader: "babel-loader",


    exclude: /node_modules/,
    query: {
      optional: ['runtime'],
      presets:['stage-0', 'es2015', 'react']
    }
  }
],
resolve: {
  extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx']
}
 }
 };
```

Comment: Did you tried to change the order in the `presets` setting? Like `[ 'es2015', 'stage-0', 'react']`?

Comment: still the same result.

Comment: Associate the source folder by including `include:/<source_folder>/`. Let me know if it works.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that regex for the test is wrong. It should be `test: /\.es6|\.js$/, loader: "babel-loader"`. Without the `|` it won't match App.js!

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing the "query" part with this:

```
query: {
   optional: ['runtime'],
   stage: 0
}
```

Otherwise, I think you have to install presets `npm install babel-preset-es2015 --save-dev`. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33470546/1043475