# How to compile Vuejs single file component?

Tags: javascript, vue-component, vue.js, vuejs2

I am using Vuejs 2 (webpack-simple template) and I would like to know how can I compile template before render it. Below my code :

**App.vue**

```
<template>
    <div id="app">
        <h1>{{ msg }}</h1>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
    export default {
        name: 'app'
    }
</script>
```

**main.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'

const res = Vue.compile(App)
const vm = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        msg: 'hello'
    },
    render: res.render,
    staticRenderFns: res.staticRenderFns
})
```

And these is the error that I've got when I start the server: `__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0_vue___default.a.compile is not a function`

I also tried this plugin [vue-template-compiler](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/blob/ff178ccc7eb9a00958240059078c7651359fce3d/packages/vue-template-compiler/README.md) with no luck. Can you please help me to make it work ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What happened when using vue-template-compiler?

Comment: @MahmudAdam I got this error : `...MyProject/node_modules/vue-template-compiler/package.json Unexpected token. You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type. ...`

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33469929/you-may-need-an-appropriate-loader-to-handle-this-file-type-with-webpack-and-b

Comment: @MahmudAdam doesn't work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need this setting in webpack's config:

```
resolve: {
  alias: {
    'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue'
  }
}
```

despite on this problem: http://vuejs.org/guide/installation.html#Standalone-vs-Runtime-only-Build

Comment: Exactly it works, but compile function support only `String` as param. Thanks for your reply @imcvampire.