# Images not loading in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm not able to display the image. I'm getting an error as not found but I have provided the full path for it. I don't know where I am going wrong.

```
class App extends React.Component {

   render() {
      return (
               <div>
                  <h1> hello</h1>    
                <img src="/home/priyanka/Finalproject/src/components/3.jpg" alt="cannot display"/>    
              </div>    
           );
         }
  }

export default App;
```

Comment: <Image source={require('./img/favicon.png')} />
[more info](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/image.html)   Remember you're dealing with JSX not plain HTML

Comment: Hope this answer helps you out
[React image/asset management ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61783390/11225762)

Answer (score 14):

If you are using `webpack`, you need to use `require` while mentioning the `src` for `img` tag. Also the url must be relative to the component.

```
class App extends React.Component {

   render() {
      return (
         <div>
  <h1> hello</h1>

<img src={require("./home/priyanka/Finalproject/src/components/3.jpg")} alt="cannot display"/>

         </div>

      );
   }
}

export default App;
```

If you are not using webpack then simplly wrapping the src value within `{}` will work

```
class App extends React.Component {

   render() {
      return (
         <div>
  <h1> hello</h1>

<img src={"./home/priyanka/Finalproject/src/components/3.jpg"} alt="cannot display"/>

         </div>

      );
   }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Are you sure the path to IMG is correct and relative to the component

Answer (score 6):

let's say you have your `images` folder inside the `public` folder.

try:

> `<img src={process.env.PUBLIC_URL + "/images/dog.png"}`

Comment: sometimes some people are like an angel in your life and right now you and your answer is playing that role for me. if i say "thank you so much", it's not enough.
after two days, reading different solutions in this website, my eyes finally caught this gold answer.

Comment: never lose hope, you'll always find a way to solve your problem. you might/will face a lot more, just take a break or a walk..., and then do your research. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

You can read [Why can't I do <img src="C:/localfile.jpg">?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4090712/why-cant-i-do-img-src-c-localfile-jpg) to know why it is not working.

If you use following method

```
import img from "/home/priyanka/Finalproject/src/components/3.jpg";
class App extends React.Component {



   render() {
      return (
         <div>
  <h1> hello</h1>

<img src={img} alt="cannot display"/>

         </div>

      );
   }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: getting an error as ERROR in ./src/components/3.jpg
Module parse failed: /home/priyanka/Finalproject/src/components/3.jpg Unexpected character '�' (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.

Comment: follow http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33469929/you-may-need-an-appropriate-loader-to-handle-this-file-type-with-webpack-and-b