# Webpack doesn't compile on linux

Tags: javascript, node.js, linux, webpack

I developed a program on windows
It successfully compiles and runs now

However, when I want to deploy it to my linux server， I get some errors:

[image]

This problem is very strange, can you help?

My webpack.config.js

```
let webpack  = require('webpack'),
    path     = require('path'),
    fs       = require('fs'),
    manifest = require('./manifest.json'),
    {resolve, join} = path,
    env = process.env.NODE_ENV;

let plugins = [
    new webpack.BannerPlugin(
        fs
          .readFileSync('./LICENSE')
          .toString('utf-8')),
    new webpack.DllReferencePlugin({context: __dirname, manifest})
];

// if (env === 'pro') {

// } else {
//  plugins.push()
// }

let config = {
        // context: resolve(__dirname, 'src'), 
    entry: {
        app: [
            './src/jsx/app.jsx',
            './src/style/app.less'
        ]
    },

    output: {
        path: resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },

    devtool: false,

    module: {
        loaders: [{
            test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            loader: 'babel-loader',     
            query: {
                presets: [
                    'stage-2',
                    'es2015',
                    'react'
                ]
            }
        },{
            test: /\.less$/,
            loader: 'style!css!autoprefixer!less'
        }]
    },

    resolve: {
        extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx']
    },

    plugins
}

module.exports = config;
```

Comment: OK...I am very poor about english...

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type" with Webpack and Babel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33469929/you-may-need-an-appropriate-loader-to-handle-this-file-type-with-webpack-and-b)

Comment: nope,  I install babel-present-es2015 and I thinked my config file was right

Comment: I complied this program on windows was successful but fail on linux

Comment: Just asking but was the app written on Windows and transferred to Linux? If so how did you do the transfer?

Comment: The app was written and transferred on windows, I just want deploy on my linux server.

Comment: On my linux server, I transferred the code again and faced this error

Comment: However, If I translated the complied file from windows to linux server,
and ran the server was successfully

Comment: So I thought this was a complie problem on linux