# You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type. Webpack and Babel

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs

I am having trouble configuring Webpack with Babel and React.

Here is my config file-

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');

var BUILD_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/client/public');
var APP_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, './app/javascripts');

var config = {
  entry: APP_DIR + '/app1.jsx',
  output: {
    path: BUILD_DIR,
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  }
};

 module : {
    loaders : [
      {
        test : /\.jsx?/,
        include : APP_DIR,
          xclude: /node_modules/,
        loader : 'babel-loader',
          query: {
        presets: ['es2015']
    }
      }
    ]
  }

module.exports = config;
```

Here is my babelrc file

```
{
  "presets" : ["es2015", "react"]
}
```

I have tried the steps as described in  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33469929/you-may-need-an-appropriate-loader-to-handle-this-file-type-with-webpack-and-b)  but still getting config error as mentioned in the title.

Comment: I don't know if this will solve your problem but here is a tip, you should switch your babel plugin from es2015 to env which is now the recommended approach.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this simple line of code instead, also, you should switch your babel plugin from es2015 `(babel-preset-es2015)` to env `(babel-preset-env)` which is now the recommended approach.

```
  module: {
    loaders: [
      { test: /\.jsx?$/, loader: 'babel-loader', exclude: /node_modules/ }
    ]
  }
```

And this should be your `.babelrc` file.

```
{
  presets: [ 'env', 'react' ]
}
```

This should work.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am getting the same error after making the change.

Comment: Are you trying to require a file which the extension was not specified in the module loaders like .scss or any else ?

Comment: No, I am not trying to require any file for which the extension was not specified in the module loaders.

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying the test expression as `\.jsx?$` and also you need not use the `.babelrc` file if you are specifying the presets in the `loaders`

```
module : {
    loaders : [
      {
        test : /\.jsx?$/,
        include : APP_DIR,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader : 'babel-loader',
          query: {
              presets: ['es2015', 'react', 'stage-0']
         }
      }
    ]
  }
```