# Can't import package to react boilerplate

Tags: javascript, npm, webpack, yarnpkg, react-boilerplate

Trying to import `react-image-crop` package using yarn and add it to `react boilerplate`.

After installing the package getting this error

```
Module parse failed: /Users/...../frontend/node_modules/react-image-crop/lib/ReactCrop.js Unexpected token (62:25)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| 
| function makeAspectCrop(crop, imageAspect) {
|   const completeCrop = { ...crop };
| 
|   if (crop.width) {
 @ ./app/components/ImageUpload/index.js 23:0-41
 @ ./app/containers/HomePage/index.js
 @ ./app/containers/HomePage/Loadable.js
 @ ./app/containers/App/index.js
 @ ./app/app.js
 @ multi eventsource-polyfill webpa
```

The boilerplate is using babylons `env` preset so the spread operator should be available.

Any ideas what may be the cause?

Comment: I personally think its gotta be with the loader config in your webpack.config.js file and not with the package itself. Check out some samples and see whether you have a loader to handle ES6 syntaxes.

Comment: @a2441918 im using the https://github.com/react-boilerplate/react-boilerplate

Comment: Check this link out. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33469929/you-may-need-an-appropriate-loader-to-handle-this-file-type-with-webpack-and-b

They have the same issue and its with the webpack config. Try adjusting it.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of importing directly from `react-image-crop` I used

```
import ReactCrop from 'react-image-crop/dist/ReactCrop';
```

and working like a charm