# Next.js - import css file does not work

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, next.js

I am creating a project with react, redux and next.js, and want to import CSS files in js.

I followed instructions in [next.js/#css](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/#css) and [next-css](https://github.com/zeit/next-plugins/tree/master/packages/next-css), but find out that CSS styles do not work.

My code is as follow:

> pages/index.js:

```
import React from 'react'
import "../style.css"

class Index extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="example">Hello World!</div>
        );
    }
}

export default Index
```

> next.config.js:

```
const withCSS = require('@zeit/next-css')
module.exports = withCSS()
```

> style.css:

```
.example {
    font-size: 50px;
    color: blue;
}
```

> package.json:

```
{
    "name": "my-app",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "private": true,
    "dependencies": {
        "@zeit/next-css": "^0.1.5",
        "next": "^6.0.0",
        "react": "^16.3.2",
        "react-dom": "^16.3.2",
        "react-redux": "^5.0.7",
        "react-scripts": "1.1.4",
        "redux": "^4.0.0",
        "redux-devtools": "^3.4.1"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
        "eject": "react-scripts eject",
        "dev": "next",
        "build": "next build",
        "start": "next start"
    }
}
```

**Questions**:

**1.** There is an "Uncaught SyntaxError" in Chrome, but it seems to not affect the rendering of the page. But I still wondering the reason and the solution. index.js error in chrome is below img

[image]

**2.** As shown in Chrome, there's no "example" class, which means the style.css file is not loaded. Am I missing anything? no CSS file in chrome

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi @ArgentBarbie, did you create the `_document.js` file in the `pages` directory? Can you paste the code in here too if you have?

Comment: @mtl Sorry, I didn't create _document.js. Is it necessary? What should be inside the file?

Comment: Hi @ArgentBarbie, in the future, try to only ask one question at a time :). If you have two questions, simply ask two separate questions. It makes it easier to answer for two different people who might only have the answers to one of the questions. And it makes the individual questions searchable, helping other people with the same issue. Good luck with Next.js!

Answer (score 29):

**EDIT 2: As of Next.js > 10**, you can import a global CSS file into `_app.js`, and you can use CSS modules in your components. More in the [Next.js docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/built-in-css-support).

---

**EDIT: As of Next.js 7**, all you have to do to support importing .css files is to register the [withCSS](https://github.com/zeit/next-plugins/tree/master/packages/next-css) plugin in your next.config.js. Start by installing the plugin as dev dependency:

```
npm install --save-dev @zeit/next-css
```

Then create the `next.config.js` file in your project root and add the following to it:

```
// next.config.js
const withCSS = require('@zeit/next-css')
module.exports = withCSS({/* my next config */})
```

You can test that this is working by creating a simple page and importing some CSS. Start by creating a CSS file:

```
// ./index.css
div {
    color: tomato;
}
```

Then create the `pages` folder with an `index.js` file. Then you can do stuff like this in your components:

```
// ./pages/index.js
import "../index.css"
export default () => <div>Welcome to next.js 7!</div>
```

You can also use CSS modules with a few lines of config. For more on this check out the documentation on [nextjs.org/docs/#css](https://nextjs.org/docs/#css).

---

**Deprecated: Next.js < 7:**

You'll also need to create a `_document.js` file in your `pages` folder and link to the compiled CSS file. Try it out with the following content:

```
// ./pages/_document.js
import Document, { Head, Main, NextScript } from 'next/document'

export default class MyDocument extends Document {
  render() {
    return (
      <html>
        <Head>
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="/_next/static/style.css" />
        </Head>
        <body>
          <Main />
          <NextScript />
        </body>
      </html>
    )
  }
}
```

The stylesheet is compiled to `.next/static/style.css` which means that the CSS file is served from `/_next/static/style.css`, which is the value of the `href` attribute in the `link` tag in the code above.

As for the first question, it's probably Chrome not understanding the import syntax. Try to enable the *Experimental Web Platform* flag in `chrome:flags` and see if that solves it.

Comment: just importing .css files affect next/router behaviour in dev mode.Some functions like `Router.push` and `replace` hangs on and doesn't work properly.

Comment: Isn't that exactly what he has in his code? I can't find a difference. I followed the same steps but its not working for me

Comment: @Jonas I agree, thats exactly what he has. I have the same and it's not working either.

Answer (score 13):

For anyone who comes here ,the new Next JS supports CSS out of the box. The catch is that for modules (components), they must be named as the component. So, if you have a header inside a `components` directory, it must be named `header.module.css`

[built-in-css-module-support-for-component-level-styles](https://nextjs.org/blog/next-9-2#built-in-css-module-support-for-component-level-styles)

Comment: Thanks mate! exactly what I needed.

Comment: For me it works as well, if the css module file name does not match the components name. So i can use the same module in two different components :)

Answer (score 4):

for next above 9.3, global css is written in "styles/globals.css" and you can import it to _app.js

```
    import "../styles/globals.css";
```

Then for each component, you can write its own css and import it into the component. Pay attention to the naming:`nameOfFile.module.css`

Let's say you have "product.js" component and "product.module.css". you want to load css from "product.css" into "product.js"

```
import classes from "./product.module.css" // assuming it's in the same directory
```

you put all class names into `product.module.css`. Assume you have `.main-product` in `product.module.css`. Inside `product.js`, let's say you have a `div` to style

```
<div className={classes.main-product}  > </div>
```

with the css module feature, you can use the same className in other components and it wont conflict. Because when next.js compiles, it will hash the name of the className, using its module. So hashed values of same classnames from different modules will be same

Answer (score 3):

Add `{name}.css` to `src/static/styles/`.

Then modify the `Head` in `src/pages/_document.js` to include the following `link`:

```html
<Head>
    <link href="/static/styles/{name}.css" rel="stylesheet">
</Head>
```

Answer (score 1):

you need create to custom **_document.js** file.

Custom document when adding css will look like:

```js
import React from "react";

import Document, { Head, Main, NextScript } from "next/document";

export default class MyDocument extends Document {

  render() {
    const { buildManifest } = this.props;
    const { css } = buildManifest;
    return (
      <html lang="fa" dir="rtl">
        <Head>
          {css.map(file => (
            <link rel="stylesheet" href={`/_next/${file}`} key={file} />
          ))}
        </Head>
        <body>
          <Main />
          <NextScript />
        </body>
      </html>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**As [Zeit](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/) said :**

1. Create a /static folder at the same level the /pages folder.
2. In that folder put your .css files
3. In your page components import Head and add a  to your CSS.

```js
import Head from 'next/head'

function IndexPage() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Head>
        <title>My page title</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, width=device-width" />
      </Head>
      <p>Hello world!</p>
    </div>
  )
}

export default IndexPage
```

And that's it, this way Next.js should render the link tag in the head of the page and the browser will download the CSS and apply it.

Thanks Sergiodxa at [Github](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/issues/299) for this clear solution.

Answer (score 1):

If you use next.js do this.

create **next.config.js** in root projects

```
const withCSS = require('@zeit/next-css');

function HACK_removeMinimizeOptionFromCssLoaders(config) {
    console.warn(
        'HACK: Removing `minimize` option from `css-loader` entries in Webpack config',
    );
    config.module.rules.forEach(rule => {
        if (Array.isArray(rule.use)) {
            rule.use.forEach(u => {
                if (u.loader === 'css-loader' && u.options) {
                    delete u.options.minimize;
                }
            });
        }
    });
}

module.exports = withCSS({
    webpack(config) {
        HACK_removeMinimizeOptionFromCssLoaders(config);
        return config;
    },
});
```

**Don't forget to restart the server**

Answer (score 1):

Global CSS Must Be in Your Custom <App>
Why This Error Occurred
An attempt to import Global CSS from a file other than pages/_app.js was made.

Global CSS cannot be used in files other than your Custom  due to its side-effects and ordering problems.

Possible Ways to Fix It
Relocate all Global CSS imports to your pages/_app.js file.

Or, update your component to use local CSS (Component-Level CSS) via CSS Modules. This is the preferred approach.

Example:

```
// pages/_app.js
import '../styles.css'

export default function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
return <Component {...pageProps} />
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set this to false if your app works directly with the web 5 package.

```
module.exports = {
  // Webpack 5 is enabled by default
  // You can still use webpack 4 while upgrading to the latest version of 
  // Next.js by adding the "webpack5: false" flag
  webpack5: false,
}
```

You can use webpack 4.

`yarn add webpack@webpack-4`