# Webpack packaging ReactDOM causing loader error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

When I run `webpack --mode development`, I get the following error:

**Edit**
A comment requested to see my .babelrc, added below
 - I've tried all combinations of index and app files as both, or each, as .jsx files, but to no avail.
 - I've also tried removing and readding all the node modules as latest version for node (v10.x.x)

```
ERROR in ./src/index.js 4:16
  Module parse failed: Unexpected token (4:16)
  You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
  | import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
  | import app from "./app.js";
 ReactDOM.render(<app />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

**app.js**

```js
import React, {Component} from "react";
import {hot} from "react-hot-loader";
import "./app.css";

class app extends Component{
  render(){
    return(
      <div className="app">
        <h1> Hello, World! </h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default app;
```

**index.js**

```js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import app from "./app.js";
ReactDOM.render(<app />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

**webpack.config.js**

```js
const path = require("path");
const webpack = require("webpack");

module.exports = {
  entry: "./src/index.jsx",
  mode: "development",
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
        loader: "babel-loader",
        options: { presets: ["@babel/env"] }
      },
      {
        test: /css\*\.css$/,
        use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"]
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: { extensions: ["*", ".js", ".jsx"] },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist/"),
    publicPath: "/dist/",
    filename: "bundle.js"
  },
  devServer: {
    contentBase: path.join(__dirname, "public/"),
    port: 3000,
    publicPath: "http://testsite.test/",
    hotOnly: true
  },
  plugins: [new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()]
};
```

```js
{
  "presets": [
    "env",
    "react",
    "stage-0"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "transform-class-properties",
    "transform-decorators",
    "transform-react-constant-elements",
    "transform-react-inline-elements"
  ]
}
```

I'm going to try and get this loaded on GH soon, but I'm having some real trouble with my GH account and connection on my device right now (ssh key issues). Bear with me on that, hopefully the above is enough to help.

**Edit #2:** Here is my github repo
https://github.com/johnfwebdev/testsite.test

Comment: Most likely does not resolve your problem, but you `import {hot} from "react-hot-loader";` in your `app.js` and don't use it.

Comment: Also name your react components with capital first letters (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30373343/reactjs-component-names-must-begin-with-capital-letters). Maybe this resolves your issue.

Comment: What does your babelrc look like? Have you tried renaming `index.js` -> `index.jsx`?

Comment: @PeterLehnhardt I updated all the locations of 'app' and changed to 'App' and removed the hot loader, unfortunately no go.

Comment: @sliptype I did try this, and app.js as app.jsx, however it produces a different error for Webpack:

> ERROR in Entry module not found: Error: Can't resolve './src' in '/Users/john.fasano/Desktop/Projects/testsite.test'

Comment: Made some updates

Comment: You should rename you class to `App` always capitalizing the first letter and on your index.js type `import { App } from "./app.js";`

Comment: @AndreF updated, but still same error.

Comment: @JohnFasano [check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33469929/you-may-need-an-appropriate-loader-to-handle-this-file-type-with-webpack-and-b)

Comment: @AndreF Tried all the things in that thread, and it was really close to my situation, but still getting the error.

Comment: So at this point I'm completely stumped. I'm going to run a quick 'create-react-app' in a throw away project to see if it works, and if not, maybe it's an environment problem? /Shrug

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out everyone.... :facepalm:

`webpack-config.js` should have been named `webpack.config.js`

Answer (score 1):

transform react jsx with babel like this, give it a try

.babelrc

```
{
  "presets": [["@babel/preset-env"]],
  "plugins": [
    "@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Tried adding this to my babelrc file, and still showing the same error.