# "You may need an appropriate loader" in React and Webpack

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack

I've been trying to use react js with webpack, but when doing "npm run build" I get the following:

```
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
| import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
| const Index = () => {
>   return <div>Welcome to React!</div>;
| };
| ReactDOM.render(<Index />, document.getElementById('app'));
 @ multi ./src/index.js ./src/scss/main.scss main[0]
```

I don't know what happens, when I start the application with "npm start" if the text comes out. Then I leave my webpack configuration file and the .babelrc.

```
 module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader"
        },

      }

    ]
  },
```

My code react:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
const Index = () => {
  return <div>Welcome to React!</div>;
};
ReactDOM.render(<Index />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

Comment: Try `use: [ { loader: "babel-loader" } ]`.

Comment: i use it........

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33469929/you-may-need-an-appropriate-loader-to-handle-this-file-type-with-webpack-and-b?rq=1

Comment: I have tried every solution to the problem, but none works.

Comment: Please add your .babelrc file.

Comment: {
  "presets": ["es2015", "stage-0", "react"]
}

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199582/discussion-between-miguel-urbina-rodriguez-and-josh-wilson).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the chat, you have in your `webpack.config.js`:

```js
module.exports = {
//...
// cargadores, los que transpilan tal formato en otro aceptable por los navegadores
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader"
        },

      }
    ]
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(sa|sc|c)ss$/,
        use: [production ? MiniCSSExtractPlugin.loader : 'style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader'],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg|gif)$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'file-loader',
            options: {
              name: 'images/[name].[ext]',
              publicPath: '../'
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(woff(2)?|ttf|eot|svg)(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'file-loader',
            options: {
              name: 'fonts/[name].[ext]',
              outputPath: '../'
            }
          }
        ]
      },
    ]
  }
};
//...
```

You have duplicate `module` fields and should combine them into

```js
module.exports = {
// cargadores, los que transpilan tal formato en otro aceptable por los navegadores
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader"
        },

      },
      {
        test: /\.(sa|sc|c)ss$/,
        use: [production ? MiniCSSExtractPlugin.loader : 'style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader'],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg|gif)$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'file-loader',
            options: {
              name: 'images/[name].[ext]',
              publicPath: '../'
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(woff(2)?|ttf|eot|svg)(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'file-loader',
            options: {
              name: 'fonts/[name].[ext]',
              outputPath: '../'
            }
          }
        ]
      },
    ]
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how your babel config file looks like but, you probably should try this:

*webpack.config.js*

```
module: {
  rules: [
    {
      test: /\.jsx$|\.js$/,
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      loader: "babel-loader",
      options: {
        presets: ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

*.babelrc*

```
{
  "presets": ["@babel/env", "@babel/react"]
}
```

This should work fine.