# jQuery lib (fancybox) styles are not found, imported css in reactjs leads to error

Tags: css, reactjs, webpack, jquery-plugins, fancybox

i've installed jquert lib FancyBox `npm install @fancyapps/fancybox --save` and followed official docs.

But the stules are not applied to fancybox dom-elements

How to apply fancybox styles? because in case if i dont import min.css into my module it runs but the styles are not applied at all (see the pictures) and on click on preview fancybox opens the picture below the footer.

```
import React from "react";
import fancybox from '@fancyapps/fancybox';
```

[image]
As you may see no css applied

[image]

In another case i add import min.css into my component but it crashes

```
import React from "react";
import '@fancyapps/fancybox/dist/jquery.fancybox.min.css';
import fancybox from '@fancyapps/fancybox';
```

with next error

```
_form_processor.js:5959 Uncaught Error: Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:16)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
(see pic)
```

[image]

My custom webpack config:

```
module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js(x?)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: { loader: "babel-loader" }
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: [".js", ".jsx"]
  },
  entry: {
    "_form_processor": "./src/index.js"
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer [that helped](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61536062/9277453) with some changes
my *.babelrc* contains next

```
{
    "presets": ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"],
    "plugins": ["@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties"]
}
```

i needed to npm install **style-loader** only
and add it to my webpack config
my present one became:

````
```module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js(x?)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: { loader: "babel-loader" }
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/i,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: [".js", ".jsx"]
  },
  entry: {
    "_form_processor": "./src/index.js"
  }
};
````

As a result the css import now works well

```
import React from "react";
import fancybox from '@fancyapps/fancybox';
import '@fancyapps/fancybox/dist/jquery.fancybox.min.css';
```

I suppose such config must be applied to every jquery lib imported with webpack