# Cloneing a React project onto a new PC

Tags: reactjs, git, git-clone

I have a very very basic react app that I made on my desktop and pushed to git. I am now trying to clone that repo and build it on my laptop. When I clone the repo I run `npm install` and when that succeeds I run `yarn start` only to be greeted by this:

[image]

I really have no idea what that message means. I am going to include my package.json in case you need it. Please ask for anything else you need. How can I resolve this issue?

This is my file structure btw:

[image]

#### Package.json

```
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.1.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.1.10",
    "bootstrap": "^4.6.0",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-bootstrap": "^1.5.0",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "web-vitals": "^1.0.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Here is the repo if you'd like to try it yourself: https://github.com/ZoeyOneOhOne/React-DOH-Template

Comment: Any reason why you're using npm and yarn? You can use 'yarn install' instead of 'npm install'. I'd suggest taking a look at your webpack config file to see what loaders it is using  and then cross check your package.json file to confirm that those are actually installed.

Comment: I honestly didn't know you could do yarn install lol. I will do that from now on.

Comment: I can't find a "webpack config file", where might that be and what might it be called?

Comment: I tried doing yarn install and couldn't help but notice that yarn install did not give me a package-lock.json but it did recreate the yarn.lock. Is this normal? Do I not need package-lock.json? Either way the same error occurred.

Comment: so Yarn and npm are just two seperate package managers. They perform the same functions and you can pick which one you want to work with. Npm just comes with Node.js. Yarn will create the yarn.lock file whereas npm will create the package-lock.json file but functionally they are the same.

Comment: @Blargian thank you very much for that info. I knew that they were both package managers, but I did not know about the package-lock and yarn lock specifics. This is very good to know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally solved this. There seems to be some issue with `react-scripts 4.0.3`. I changed this line in package.json:

`"react-scripts": "4.0.3",`

to

`"react-scripts": "4.0.1",`

and everything is working fine now.

Answer (score 0):

delete `node_modules` and `package-lock.json` or `yarn.lock` and then enter `npm cache clean --force` , `npm install`

Most likely the problem will be solved

Comment: I deleted node_modules, package-lock.json, and yarn.lock and then ran the commands you said. Same error occurred upon running yarn start. What next?

Comment: this way maybe work

step1: `npm install --save-dev @babel/preset-env`

step2: create `.babelrc` file inside root path of your project where webpack.config.js exists.

then add this code to .babelrc

`{"presets": ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"]}`

Comment: I do not have a webpack.config.js file. I updated the question to show you the file structure.

Comment: follow this process: 

https://stackoverflow.com/a/61536062/10625740

Comment: I think you have misunderstood. I do not have a webpack.config.js file. I can not complete step 4: "Step-4: create .babelrc file inside root path path of your project where webpack.config.js exists." because webpack.config.js does NOT exist. What do I do?

Comment: if you don't have webpack.config.js, just create in the root path and then paste step5: code into it. maybe this work because I had already concluded from this method

Comment: Ok I did that. Same error message though. I also found webpack.config.js in react-scripts > config folder. But after following all the steps from the link you posted I got the same error message.

Comment: I have included a link to the repo if you want to try to build it yourself.

Comment: that's a very strange problem. what's your node version?

Comment: I am using node v14.15.1

Comment: i clone that in my system and run it, in my system without problem program, is running

Comment: remove your node and install again maybe the problem fixed

Comment: Uninstalled and reinstalled Node. Same error.

Comment: please delete your node_modules and package-lock.json and yarn.lock and then enter `yarn` command on the console, please don't use npm i, just yarn and then enter `yarn start`, this is the way i went, and I got the result and project run

Comment: restart your computer maybe node server has a problem

Comment: I did this and still got the same error. You are the 3rd person so confirm it working. It also runs fine on my desktop. Just not my laptop.

Comment: try clone again and follow yarn method maybe work fine
What operating system is installed on the laptop?

Comment: I have re cloned it every time I tried. I'm using Windows 10.

Comment: if you have another react project on your laptop, try to run that, maybe problem in your laptop windows

Comment: I will do that. I recently tried to create an app from scratch on this laptop and had problems. Thank you very much for the help.