# You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. (webpack)

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babel-loader

Im trying to configure webpack for React.
But when i ran "npm run start" i got this error in VSC console:

```
ERROR in ./src/index.js 5:16
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (5:16)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
| import App from "./components/App";
|
> ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("app"));
|
```

webpack.config.js:

```
const path = require("path");
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");

module.export = {
  entry: "./src/index.js",
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
    filename: "bundle.js",
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: [".js", ".jsx"],
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js|\.jsx$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader",
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        use: [{ loader: "html-loader" }],
      },
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: "./public/index.html",
      filename: "./index.html",
    }),
  ],
  devServer: {
    static: path.join(__dirname, "dist"),
    compress: true,
    port: 3000,
  },
};
```

Index.js:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import App from "./components/App";

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("app"));
```

Package.json:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2"
  },
  "name": "curso-webpack-react",
  "description": "",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.15.5",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.15.6",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.14.5",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.2",
    "html-loader": "^2.1.2",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.3.2",
    "prettier": "2.4.1",
    "webpack": "^5.53.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.8.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^4.2.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "webpack-dev-server",
    "build": "webpack --mode production"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/platzi/curso-webpack-react.git"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/platzi/curso-webpack-react/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/platzi/curso-webpack-react#readme"
}
```

.babelrc:

```
{
    "presets": [
        "@babel/preset-env",
        "@babel/preset-react"
    ]
}
```

I don't know what to try anymore.
Iv tried to change `test: /\.(.js|jsx)$/,` to `test: /\.js$|jsx/,` or `test: /\.js|\.jsx$/`, but no results.
Iv also tried others solutions to the same problems that iv saw in others stackoverflow publications, but no results tho.

Comment: Please [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33469929/you-may-need-an-appropriate-loader-to-handle-this-file-type-with-webpack-and-b)

Comment: @hisam iv already read that, iv tried all those solutions, but no one worked for me.