# Opening an external html file from a react app

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, webpack-html-loader

I have a react app, which i make thought create-react-app. I want to make here a link, that will refer to project.html file. I tried to make something like this:

```
const Portfolio = (props) => {
    return (
            <a href="../projects/project.html" target="_blank">
                <button>Go to this project</button>
            </a>
    )
}
```

But this lead me to http://localhost:3000/projects/project.html and react app.
I also tried to import this path like:

```
import html from "../projects/project.html"
```

and then to do something like this:

```
        <a href={html} target="_blank">
            <button>Go to this project</button>
        </a>
```

but react say that i need some loader for this. I find that there are html-loader, i install it by `npm install --save-dev html-loader` and add configuration to webpack.config.js but nothing changed

Comment: What does _"refer to project.html file"_ mean?

Comment: Where is the `project.html` file at? Can you share your folder's hierarchy?

Comment: refer to project.html file mean that i want open project.html when i click the button.

Folder's hierarchy: https://ibb.co/C8SWBTS, project.html in projects folder

Comment: HTML forbids `<button>` elements inside `<a>` elements.

Answer (score 0):

If your `projects/project.html` file contains only static content and does not require anything from the codebase, you could move the `projects` folder to the `public` folder, and link to that file in your React component with:

```js
const Portfolio = (props) => {
    return (
            <a href="/projects/project.html" target="_blank">
                Go to this project
            </a>
    )
}
```

Answer (score -1):

First install html loader using

```
npm install --save-dev html-loader
```

Add below lines to your webpack.config file

```
{
  project: /\.(html)$/,
  use: {
    loader: 'html-loader',
    options: {
      attrs: [':data-src']
    }
  }
}
```

Now you can import like this

```
import Page from './project.html';
var htmlDoc = {__html: Page};
```

Then, in return block of react, use like this

```
<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={htmlDoc} />
```

Comment: nothing changed, react say:`Compiled with problems:X

ERROR in ./src/projects/piano/index.html 1:0

Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
> <!DOCTYPE html>
| <html>
| <head>`
i have several projects, i say that i want to open project.html to have some general solution for all projects, but if it important i have a project folder inside which i have projects folders 
 and inside every of this project i have index.html

Comment: https://ibb.co/MhwDRKV
full folder's hierarchy

Comment: @Gleb please refer this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33469929/you-may-need-an-appropriate-loader-to-handle-this-file-type-with-webpack-and-b