# You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file for TailwindCss

Tags: css, reactjs, tailwind-css, webpack-style-loader

I'm using tailwindcss for the first time, using tutorials I found online. So far npm installed tailwindcss, postcss, postcss-loader, autoprefixer. From Tailwind docs, I needed a tailwind.config.js and postcss.config.js.

tailwind.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  content: ["./client/*.{html,js}", "./client/**/*.{html,js}"],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
    container: {
      center: true,
    },
  },
};
```

postcss.config.js:

```
const tailwind = require("tailwindcss");
module.exports = {
  plugins: [tailwind("./tailwind.config.js"), require("autoprefixer")],
};
```

I even have a build script for tailwind :

```
 "build:css": "postcss public/tailwind.css -i public/style.css",
```

In my tailwind.css file I added the Tailwind directives :

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

What kind of loader do I need in my webpack? In addition, I get this under the problems tab in my terimal : [image: SS of problem]

On my browser terminal I get this in the console.log :
[image]

Any tips on how to fix this and start styling my app?

Comment: Are you using CRACO?

Comment: @kellys Nope, first time hearing CRACO

Comment: how did you install it?

Comment: @Dhaifallah tailwindcss? with npm i tailwindcss, same from postcss and autoprefixer

Comment: @PJK hope u found a solution, but If not this might be related to `es2015` preset configuration have a look [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33469929/you-may-need-an-appropriate-loader-to-handle-this-file-type-with-webpack-and-b)

Answer (score 0):

Write this:

```
@import 'tailwindcss/base';

@import 'tailwindcss/components';

@import 'tailwindcss/utilities';
```

instaead of :

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities
```

Answer (score -1):

Use this code to install a loader: `npm install --save-dev postcss-loader postcss`

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please edit your answer to fix it, since at this state, it can currently cause lots of confusion. That is not code, it is a terminal command. Please also tell them what it does/fixes and how it helps. Read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer