# react-three/postprocessing. Module parse failed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, react-three-fiber

As soon as import Effect Composer into an active document, I get this error message. Could there be a possibility of my model/material causing this?? I am not even using the Effect Composer in Script. Or could it be that I need some kind of background??

*./node_modules/screen-space-reflections/dist/index.js 675:33
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (675:33)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
|   var boneMatrices = material[boneMatricesName];
|

> if (material[boneMatricesName]?.length !== skeleton.boneMatrices.length) {
> |     delete material[boneMatricesName];
> |     boneMatrices = new Float32Array(skeleton.boneMatrices.length);*

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import App from './App';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import './styles.css'
import { EffectComposer } from '@react-three/postprocessing'
//I just inserted it here to see if this causes the failure and it does


const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <App />
  </BrowserRouter>
);
```

Comment: Turns out that my npm and node were outdated, downloading older versions of r3f and such
updating npm then reinstalling everything solved it

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to install the es2015 preset??

REF: ["You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type" with Webpack and Babel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33469929/you-may-need-an-appropriate-loader-to-handle-this-file-type-with-webpack-and-b)

npm install babel-preset-es2015

You need to install the es2015 preset:

```
npm install babel-preset-es2015
```

and then configure babel-loader:

```
{
    test: /\.jsx?$/,
    loader: 'babel-loader',
    exclude: /node_modules/,
    query: {
        presets: ['es2015']
    }
}
```

Maybe you need to add the file-loader under your modules.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/file-loader

webpack.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif)$/i,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'file-loader',
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
};
```