# Typescript / Webpack check if running via Production config

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack

I am using `webpack, reactjs, typescript`. In my `.tsx` code, I have a requirement where I need to route to URL depending upon my environment i.e. Production or Development. So, how can I check for the environment and load the correct URL **dynamically** ?

Comment: using environment variables is one option - https://webpack.js.org/guides/environment-variables/

Comment: How will that help `dynamically` i.e.  during actual code execution ? Config is only used during the `build process`. Could you please elaborate with a sample if possible ?

Comment: Hi @AngshumanAgarwal, have you achieved something? I would like to have some feedback on my answer

Comment: Thanks for your answer - researched more and found that `webpack` has nicely documented it too - https://webpack.js.org/guides/production/

Comment: @AngshumanAgarwal Woah, that's cool. I didn't know that. Going to apply it to my projects haha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a plugin to define an environment variable that can be accessed within the code, like this:

```
new webpack.DefinePlugin({
    'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('production')
})
```

And then inside your code you just have to check for `process.env.NODE_ENV`.

Needless to say that you can manage the plugin with an environment variable that you can pass via cli, like this:

```
webpack --env.production
```

And then have your `webpack.config.js` with something like this:

```
module.exports = function(env) {
    return {
        /*[...]*/
        plugins: [new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify(env.production ? 'production' : 'development')
        })]
        /*[...]*/
    };
};
```

Source: That's how react works :-)

Comment: Thanks - will give a shot at it. My understanding is since the NODE_ENV environment variable and the corresponding process.env.NODE_ENV runtime field are strictly Node-specific concepts, by default that value does not exist in client-side code. Looks like DefinePlugin is forcing that to be a global variable ?

Comment: @AngshumanAgarwal Exactly, `DefinePlugin` makes that inside any webpack bundle code running in any environment will have the defined variable.

Comment: Hope `UglifyJS` does not strip that out as a dead code brach during minification because it will encounter `if("production" !== "production")` where `process.env.NODE_ENV = "production"` -- as being set from the cli during the build process.

Comment: @AngshumanAgarwal There's no problem with that, as if the branch is never reached, you don't need the code inside it. Is actually good to strip it to reduce bundle size.

Comment: import using "require" worked for me: `new (require('webpack')).DefinePlugin({ ...`